# Create an empty DF using schema from another DF (Scala Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to compare a DF with another one that is the same schema readed from a specific path, but maybe in that path there are not files so I've thought that I have to compare it with a null DF with the same columns as the original.

So **I am trying to create a DF with the schema from another DF that contains a lot of columns** but I can't find a solution for this. I have been reading the following posts but no one helps me:

[How to create an empty DataFrame with a specified schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477598/how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe-with-a-specified-schema)

[How to create an empty DataFrame? Why "ValueError: RDD is empty"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624681/how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe-why-valueerror-rdd-is-empty)

[How to create an empty dataFrame in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606520/how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe-in-spark)

How can I do it in scala? Or is better take other option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`originalDF.limit(0)` will return an empty dataframe with the same schema.